# How does this set is bounded above

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a set

$$A=\{p\in\Bbb Q^+\mid p^2 < 2\}$$

My instructor told me that A is bounded above.  But I am not sure how this is?  This is because he gave definition of upper bound in which it is written that upper bound should belong to ordered set.

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The maximum of $A$ is not defined because there is no "maximal" number $x$ in $A$ such $x^2 < 2$ and such that every other number in $A$ are less than $x$. However there is a supremum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bounded from above by $2$. Assume $p \in A, p \geq 2$. Then $2 > p^2 \geq 4$, which is a contradiction.